# How to setup Bootstrap table responsive mobile layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4alpha.

I have a table listing a companies services.

In mobile (sm) view I would like the cells to fall into a single column. Perhaps in tablet (md) view I may want two columns.

What classes can I use to accomplish this, or would I be smarter starting again using bootstrap rows and columns rather than a table?

```
<table class="table table-sm" style="border-top:2px solid #777;" >
<tbody>
    <tr style="border:0;">
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Truck Tarps</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Taut Liner Curtains</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Roll Tops</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Cap Tarps</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:0;">
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Load Resistant Curtains</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Custom Covers</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Heavy Duty Canvas Canopy</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid #fff;">Tarp Repairs / Onsite Repairs</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: u using bootstrap, i believe you can get huge info in their web page on how to make it

Comment: use bootstrap rows and columns rather than a table, in your scenario that would be easier and fluid

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a table-specific construct in Bootstrap 4 for this as far as I know, however essentially you just want table cells to turn into block elements on narrow viewports. You can set display property overrides with Bootstrap 4 beta's [responsive display utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/), but that could get messy as it's mobile-first and you'll need to correct the override for medium viewports upwards.

Easier to just enter in custom css in your own media queries, e.g.

```
@media all and (max-width: [your-breakpoint]) {
  table, tr, td {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

You can also use heading specific styles on `th` elements, and add spacing to `tr` elements to make your table appear clearer when stacked.

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/) has some good thoughts on responsive tables.

Semantically though, with your example there doesn't appear to be an real reason why you're using a table; this is really just a list. Putting it into a table is just causing you a responsive headache unecessarily. If I were you I'd be using a `<ul>` list and styling it from there.